# Data Warehouse with SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

I am working on a project to create a data warehouse. I have installed SQL Server 2012 Management Studio for this purpose. However, When I showed the software to my tutor, he said that there is no Data warehouse folder within the Object Explorer. He thought Microsoft provided special management studio to support Business Intelligence i.e. for Data warehouse like Oracle and their enterprise version.
Is there any special editions Microsoft providing for Data Warehouse other than the one I have? And if there is any, where would I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several moving pieces.  First you need to ensure that the SQL Server that your connecting to has SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) installed and running.  Second, when you attach to the server, you need to connect to **Analysis Services** rather than a **Database Engine**

I cannot recall from memory, but a possible third issue is that you did not choose the Analysis Services components when you installed SSMS, but I think they get installed by default if I recall.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How do I ensure the SSAS is actually installed within the SSMS ?

Comment: To ensure the services are installed and running on the server, you would need to look at the running services and find **SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER)** and ensure it's running.  If it's not there, it's not installed (you can check with DBA if you don't have server access).  Within SSMS, you click the **Connect** button within the Object Explorer and choose **Analysis Servivces*

Comment: Thank you again. I did click on the Connect button ad choose the Analysis service. It opened databases and assemblies folders! Does this mean I am ok to work with the SSMS ?

Comment: You'll use SSMS as a management tool just to monitor the server and run tasks, etc.  To actually develop cubes or other objects for SSAS, then you'll need to use Visual Studio with the Business Intelligence features.  (BTW, if this answers your question, please mark as answer :) )

Comment: Thank you once more for answering my queries. I already installed SQL Server Data Tools! When you said Visual Studio did you mean the Visual Studio 2010 Shell as an example of this? I really appreciate your help:)

Comment: Yes - it's dependent on the server version of SQL Server.  Check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166989(v=sql.130).aspx) and  change the SQL Server version that matches yours to determine exactly which version you need.